# Grant to select on synonym through database_link

Tags: sql, oracle

I have administrative problem on my database.

I need to give permission to other schema to my View. My View have data from one table and view. This Second view is using private database link.

How can i `grant select` on that View, to other schema and in the same time grant view that is using database link?

While trying making simple

`grant select on myView to otherSchema;`

i have error `ORA-02021: DDL operations are not allowed on a remote database`

Answer (score 0):

DDL operations of any kind, such as grants, are not allowed to be executed through a database link. You need to connect to the remote database where the source objects are located, and grant select on them to the user/schema who connects by dblink. As you don't provide any code, consider the option that you might need to use `grant select on xxxx with grant option`.